# removal of words from string, but order matters

Tags: python, regex

I have a list of words I want to remove from a string such as `['as', 'as well as']`

The string is `he is big as hell, as well as an elephant`

I want to loop thru the list and get rid of all the words in the list

```
remove=['as','as well as']
sentence='he is big as hell, as well as an elephant'

for i in remove:
    sentence=sentence.replace(" " + i + " "," ")
```

desired output: `he is big hell, an elephant`

actual output: `he is big hell, well an elephant`

It's basically removing the `as` before it gets to the `as well as` therefore `well` remains. What can I do to prevent this without putting `as well as` first in the list?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do sorting according to the length of each item  then  iterate over the contents and finally do replace.

```
>>> sentence='he is big as hell, as well as an elephant'
>>> remove=['as','as well as']
>>> remove = sorted(remove, key=lambda x: len(x), reverse=True)
>>> remove
['as well as', 'as']
>>> for i in remove:
    sentence=sentence.replace(" " + i + " "," ")

>>> sentence
'he is big hell, an elephant'
```

Comment: this doesn't work if the sentence begins with "as well as"... `as well as he is big as hell, as well as an elephant`

Comment: use , `re.sub` like `sentence=re.sub(r"\b" +  i + r"\b","", sentence)`

Answer (score 2):

I think that the most straight forward way to it would be to order your filtered words by length so that the longest things that need to be removed are removed first.

edit: here is the sort by length method I found:
`remove.sort(key=len, reverse=True)`

Comment: Avinash already got it for you but the answer I found is to use array.sort(key=len, reverse=True)

Answer (score 0):

Python lists have a *reverse()* method. If you know the order of the list contents is just the reverse of what you want, then implement that before removing each list item.